# Equivalence condition for diagonalization of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

When $n\geq 1$ is  integer, $A$ is $n\times n$ regular real matrix, $f$ is linear transformation of $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $A$. We take

$$S=\{V\subset {\mathbb{R}}^n:{\rm subspace}\mid {\rm dim}V=n-1,f(V)=V\}$$
then the following two condition is equivalent.

1. A is diagonalized by real regular matrix
2. $S\neq \phi$ and $\displaystyle\bigcap_{V\in S}V={0}$

I have shown 1$\Longrightarrow$2, but I still haven't showed  2$\Longrightarrow$1 , any hint please.

Comment: What's regular matrix in this context?

Comment: "regular" means its determinants is not zero. Of course it has inverse matrix.

Comment: The term for a matrix with a non-zero determinant is “non-singular”, or equivalently, “invertible”.

Comment: Context: what is $\phi$?

Comment: \phi means empty set now.

Answer (score 0):

Hints (Assuming knowledge about invariant factor decomposition):
We can write $\Bbb R^n=\oplus_{i=1}^m V_i$ where each $V_i$ is $f$-cyclic and indecomposable, i.e. $V_i\cong \Bbb R[t]/\langle p_i^{n_i}\rangle$ for some irreducible polynomials $p_i\in\Bbb R$ and $n_i\in\Bbb N$. We want to show that $\dim V_i=1$ for all $i$.
Assume that $\dim V_1>1$.

- Prove that any nonzero submodule of $\Bbb R[t]/\langle p_1^{n_1}\rangle$ contains $\langle p_1^{n_1-1}\rangle/\langle p_1^{n_1}\rangle\ne0$
- Show that for any $V\in S$ the intersection $V\cap V_1$ is non-zero and also $f$-invariant, thus a ($\Bbb R[t]$-)submodule of $V_1$.
- Combine the previous two points to derive a contradiction with the assumption $\bigcap_{V\in S}V = 0$.

Comment: I can't show that $V\cap V_1$ is non-zero, however I thought for a while. Using the fact dimension of V is n-1?Any hint please

Comment: Yes, that is needed. Note that because $n_1>1$ we have $\dim V_1\geq 2$. Combine this with $\dim V=n-1$. What can we say about $\dim V_1+V$ and its relation to $\dim V_1, \dim V, \dim V_1\cap V$?